# Why XCode 7.1 compiles code everytime I write code?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I working on an iOS application in Swift and **each time I write code or chose a name of variable/method from list, XCode compiles project**. It can be seen from the processor usage graph that is not an visual-only problem.

This slows down my mac, variable/methods suggestions appears also slow...

[image]

[image]

[image]

I have updated to XCode 7.1.1 but still does that. Any suggestions?

Comment: Weird!  That sucks.  Wish I had an answer...  Personally, I write iOS app in an external IDE (Qt Creator) and just compile through XCode. I still need to use it sometimes, but I avoid it.  If needed, perhaps you could use an older version for editing, and then just compile with 7.1.1?

Comment: Hey there. It must be a problem with my XCode because I saw nobody complained about it.. I love XCode and hope I can find another solution instead of re-downloading it on my turle-speed-network

Comment: Do you have any `@IBDesignable` `UIView` subclasses in your project?

Comment: @CharlesA. thanks for the reply. I'm not using *@IBDesignable* but check out the Marked answer. Turns out that that's the problem

Comment: @SilviuSt Good to know.  Glad you sorted it out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same issue some weeks ago and I finally found hat it's because I used 2 Xcode's windows: one for the storyboard and one for the code. As soon as I stopped using 2 windows, XCode stopped to build my storyboard after every code update.
Note that I'm not talking about tabs but windows.

Comment: Hi there live-saviour. Indeed that's what crossed my mind after CharlesA comment. Turns out that that's the problem but you have an explanation for that? Just curious. Thanks

Comment: I really don't know, but I suspect its linked with the fact that an opened storyboard is considered as modified. If a process is performed with storyboards each time some code is updated (let's say IBOutlet's state refresh for example), maybe the fact the storyboard is never really saved is forcing XCode to keep building it.

Comment: I see now but find this kinda awkward not to see what class has been modified when 2 are opened

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a view that is defined as IB Designable and not in a framework? If so, Xcode will recompile your project when code changes. One option is to comment out the designable directive until you need to modify the class again.